# With either A1 or R1C1 notation, why is it necessary to getRange?

Tags: google-apps-script

Can anyone suggest what or where to read, or can tell me; With either A1 or R1C1 notation, why is it necessary to getRange?

Comment: What?!`````````````````​`````````````````

Comment: Well your question is not clear but from my understanding I think getRange is the function to locate the range within any sheet and the notation A1 or R1C1 are pointing to specified range. Post using getRange various other tasks can be performed on the range. Basically getRange selects the specified range to do operation on it.

Comment: Let's think about it in another way - how else would you get the range, if it weren't for the `getRange()` method?

Comment: How do you expect the code to know for which range you want to get the formulas or values? If you talk to a robot and ask it to give you some values from a sheet, it will ask you what values? Every value or from a particular range ?

Comment: Why is it necessary to have to state the range that is going to be used? Can't the function or procedure have the range stated within the function as parameters? Ok, then. What happens if a cell is referenced out side of the getRange()?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*As the Mind-Reading API doesn't seem to be public, at the moment it is necessary to tell Apps Script the range on which you wish to apply changes or get values.*

#### More Information:

From your question and comments I think you misunderstand how Apps Script works.

To answer your question *"With either A1 or R1C1 notation, why is it necessary to getRange"*.

You see, computers aren't clever. They do exactly what you tell them to do, and need very specific instructions so that they make sense.

When you run a script in Apps Script on a Spreadsheet, `getRange` is the way of using A1 or R1C1 notation to tell a script where to apply the code to.

#### Working Example:

Let's say in `Sheet1`, the first row is a list of headings:

[image]

And you would like to have the headings in **bold** without the data below it being **bolded** as well.

You would have to, in your script, specify exactly which range of cells you want to change the font styling on - this is done by specifying the range with `getRange()`:

```js
function exampleFunction() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var headingRange = sheet.getRange("A1:D1")
  
  headingRange.setFontWeight("bold")  
}
```

This emboldens the cells in the specified range to be bold. Without telling Apps Script which range to apply the changes to, it wouldn't know where you want to do it.

#### Alternative signatures of `getRange()`:

It is worth noting however, that the `Sheet` class of Apps Script has [multiple ways of specifying a range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column). The first, most intuitive way, is using the A1 notation which we used in the example above:

<sub>**NB:** In these examples I use the `activate()` method in Apps Script to visualise what each of the ranges would look like.</sub>

> #### `getRange(a1Notation)`
>
> Returns the range as specified in A1 notation or R1C1 notation.
>
> ```js
> // Get a range A1:D4 on sheet titled "Sheet1"
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var range = ss.getRange("Sheet1!A2:D4");
>
> // Get cell A3 on the first sheet
> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
> var cell = sheet.getRange("A3");
> ```

**Visual Sample for `getRange(a1Notation)`:**

[image]

[image]

---

The second way of getting a range is by specifying a specifc cell using its row and column indicies:

> #### `getRange(row, column)`
>
> Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates.
>
> ```
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
> // Passing only two arguments returns a "range" with a single cell.
> var range = sheet.getRange(2, 3);
> ```

**Visual Sample for `getRange(row, column)`:**

[image]

---

The third way is similar to the second, but you can also specify a number of rows as a third parameter:

> #### `getRange(row, column, numRows)`
>
> Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates, and with the given number of rows.
>
> ```
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
> // When the "numRows" argument is used, only a single column of data is returned.
> var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 3);
> ```

**Visual Sample for `getRange(row, column, numRows)`:**

[image]

---

And finally in the fourth way, you can specify both the number of rows, and the number of column, on top of the starting row and column:

> #### `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`
>
> Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates with the given number of rows and columns.
>
> ```
> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
> var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 3, 3);
> ```

**Visual Sample for `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`:**

[image]

#### References:

- [Chass Sheet - getRange() | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand your question better by reading your comment. If I'm not mistaken, you are asking why the following syntax is necessary:

```
sheet.getRange("A2: L20").setValues(arr);
```

As opposed to something like:

```
sheet.setValues("A2: L20", arr);
```

As you mentioned, this syntax would be useful when it comes to referring to multiple ranges, where you *may* find yourself using `getRange()` repeatedly followed by the function(s) you wish to apply.

### Answer:

However, I think the answer to your question might come down to performance.

With this syntax not using `getRange()`, the script will still need to get the data you are working with behind the scenes. In this case, this would occur within the functions where the ranges are specified.

If you do use `getRange()` repeatedly as previously mentioned, you may have noticed the poor performance doing so causes. As such, having each function you perform getting ranges would be a terrible hit to performance.

The following is according to [Google Apps Scripts Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices),

> Anything you can accomplish within Google Apps Script itself will be much faster than making calls that need to fetch data from Google's servers or an external server, such as requests to Sheets...

Given this, having `getRange()` may indeed make sense, as it gives the programmer the power to specify when, where, and how fetching data should occur.